# Cómo pasar información de una variable php a una de javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Me gustaría poder obtener la información de la variable php y pasarla a la variable javascript.

```js
// NECESITO PASAR LA INFORMACIÓN DE LA VARIABLE DE PHP A ESTA VARIABLE JAVASCRIPT

var a = [];


<?php 

$variable = "esta información";

?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas pasar datos de PHP a Javascript? ¿De dónde provienen esos datos? Hoy día se usa generalmente Ajax o la API fetch para comunicar entre cliente (Javascript) y servidor (PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Usa [JavaScript InLine](https://www.googleessimple.com/wiki/pagespeed/utilizar-javascript-en-linea/#:%7E:text=El%20JavaScript%20en%20l%C3%ADnea%20simplemente,de%20mostrar%20tu%20p%C3%A1gina%20web.) Para definir la variable que quieres y le pasas como parámetro la variable php.

```
$a = "Hola Mundo!";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
let variable =  $a;
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Pero cómo se hace si se está trabajando en un archivo php?

Comment: El Archivo php te permite escribir HTML. Dentro de tu etiquetas body pones: <script></script> con el código JavaScript dentro, a esto se le conoce como JavaScript InLine.

Comment: Casi está listo, solo falta hacer `echo` de la variable: `let variable =  '<?php echo $a; ?>';`